# How are secondary kotlin constructor variables passed in?

Tags: constructor, kotlin

I am looking at the solution for the `gigasecond` exercism exercise for `Kotlin`: http://exercism.io/exercises/kotlin/gigasecond/readme. I can understand how it needs two two constructor because `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` arguments are passed in when creating the class. What I don't understand is how the below secondary class constructor variables are passed in and used in the class. It seems like the calculation only happens when `LocalDateTime` arguments are passed in, as calculation is only done with `dobWithTime`. What magic is happening here ?

```
data class Gigasecond(val dobWithTime: LocalDateTime) {
    constructor(dateOfBirth: LocalDate) : this(dateOfBirth.atStartOfDay())

    val date: LocalDateTime = dobWithTime.plusSeconds(1000000000)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The secondary constructor just forwards the call to primary constructor with the `: this()` syntax, while creating the required `LocalDateTime` object from the `LocalDate` that it received as its parameter.

You could think of the secondary constructor as a function that does the following:

```
fun createGigaSecond(dateOfBirth: LocalDate): Gigasecond {
    return Gigasecond(dateOfBirth.atStartOfDay())
}
```

Except it gets to use the usual constructor syntax instead, and so it can be called as `Gigasecond(dataOfBirth)` instead of `createGigaSecond(dateOfBirth)`.

---

From the official documentation about [secondary constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#secondary-constructors):

> If the class has a primary constructor, each secondary constructor needs to delegate to the primary constructor, either directly or indirectly through another secondary constructor(s). Delegation to another constructor of the same class is done using the `this` keyword.

This is what's happening here.